# Rails: many_to_many relationship within one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have two groups, teacher and student, both of them are users
I use teacher = true to mark user as a teacher, student = true mark user as student

But actually I want a student model and a teacher model like this

```
teacher has_many students,  through: :class
student has_many teachers,  through: :class
```

Problem is that I do not know how to make two model all log in as users.
Anybody could help? Thanks.
[image: I want like this]

Comment: You could sub-class the user-model (ie use single-table inheritance)
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the solution I want.

Comment: You should only subclass if you want significantly different functionality between students and teachers across the app.

Comment: @ruby_newbie I updated question, do you think STI suits my problem?

Comment: @TarynEast I just added a pic for better explain. I am not sure STI or Polymophic accociations suits my problem

Comment: I don't know the exact specs of your project but maybe adding a role enum[:student, :teacher] in the user model maybe solve your problem in a simpler way.

Comment: You can probably solve it without STI if you want... but if you have different methods for students vs teachers (and no student will ever also be a teacher eg a tutor) then STI will work. Otherwise, you will need to use more specific joins - eg `has_many students,  through: :class, class_name: User.name, foreign_key: :student_id` (which needs checking for bugs and typos)

Comment: I would do what Taryn East suggested personally.  Seems like the best solution.

Comment: @TarynEast Thanks. I tried STI, problem is there are many attributes are not shared, like student model have stu_id, stu_parent, stu_birthplace. teacher model have teacher_id, teacher_workyear, teacher_salary.  So, I hope to create student table and teacher table, STI seems only allow derived model to use base model table one.

Comment: @TarynEast I mean STI suits my problem, only problem is caused column wasted in user table.

Comment: @TarynEast And how to generate student_id ,and teacher_id automatically , because they have many to many relationship, I hope to store their id into the bridge table called class.

Comment: two tables works well. you could pull the duplicate columns out into a "contact details" table and a student `has_one :contact_detail` and  a teacher `has_one :contact_detail` thus removing the duplication from the table, and allowing you to search over the common `contact-details` table.

Comment: Regarding student_id/teach_id... you will probably need a join table for that. Have you read the official Rails Guides ? it will give you the idea on how to go about actually doing this stuff (and is also a great way to level up on your rails knowledge - well worth reading them all, all the way through). In this case you can do with the info in this one: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: @TarynEast Thank you. I will read it carefully and tried one more time